# Random forest splitting rule and importance in package ranger

Tags: r, random-forest, cart

The package `ranger` implements random forests in R. Among other things, the function used to fit a random forest allows to choose among several splitting rules, and several ways to compute the importance of the features. The documentation says:

For importance:

> Variable importance mode, one of 'none', 'impurity',
> '**impurity_corrected**', 'permutation'. The 'impurity' measure is the
> Gini index for classification, the variance of the responses for
> regression and the sum of test statistics (see splitrule) for
> survival.

What is impurity_corrected? I understand that impurity in regression is a measure based on the variance reduction for each split where the considered variable is used, but how is it corrected?

For splitting rules:

> Splitting rule. For classification and probability estimation "gini",
> "extratrees" or "hellinger" with default "gini". For regression
> "variance", "extratrees", "**maxstat**" or "**beta**" with default "variance".
> For survival "logrank", "extratrees", "C" or "maxstat" with default
> "logrank".

What are maxstat and beta splitting rules in a regression setting?

Comment: `impurity_corrected` is discussed in the documentation, with a reference to Nembrini et al. (2018).

Answer (score 0):

I think it refers to maximally selected rank statistics.
There is a paper talking about it : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.03391.pdf.